# Unable to run Gradle commands because of JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: java, gradle, web-development-server

I installed java 8 in my Mac Big sur. I want to execute gradlew farmrun command, but it is showing that my java_home is set to an invalid directory. But I already have my java_home location in bash_profile and path is set properly.
[Not able to execute gradle command - picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvUFE.jpg)

[Java home was set properly - picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvumw.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? First picture you shared shows an error when sourcing the `.zshrc`. file.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].